# Submit form via jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

I am trying to call a function when the form submit button is clicked. The page should not refresh, I want to add the category via AJAX.

The problem is that everything works fine when I add it manually to the html file, but when I try to add it in the javascript function via `appendTo`, the click function is never called. What is the problem here?

Javascript:

```
$(".addCategoryBtn").click(function() {  
       console.log('add category clicked');
    });
```

Part of the JavaScript function:

```
html += '<br><br><form id="addCategory_form" action=""><input type="text" class="inptCategoryName" placeholder="Kategorie Name">&nbsp;<input type="text" class="inptHtmlColor" placeholder="Hintergrund: #000FFF">&nbsp;<input type="text" class="inptTextColor" placeholder="Text: #000FFF"><input type="button" value="Go" class="addCategoryBtn"></form></div>';

$(html).appendTo($('body'));
```

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML so I can look for errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dynamic content, when using jquery 1.7 or later, use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("body").on('click','.addCategoryBtn',function() {  
    console.log('add category clicked');
});
```

For jQuery 1.6.x and lower, including 1.4.3 use [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$("body").delegate('.addCategoryBtn', 'click', function() {  
   console.log('add category clicked');
});
```

For jQuery 1.4.2 or lower use [**bind**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) after the append:

```
html += '<br><br><form id="addCategory_form" action=""><input type="text" class="inptCategoryName" placeholder="Kategorie Name">&nbsp;<input type="text" class="inptHtmlColor" placeholder="Hintergrund: #000FFF">&nbsp;<input type="text" class="inptTextColor" placeholder="Text: #000FFF"><input type="button" value="Go" class="addCategoryBtn"></form></div>';

$(html).appendTo($('body'));

$(".addCategoryBtn").bind("click", function() {  
    console.log('add category clicked');
});
```

Eitherway, what ever you do, try to avoid [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with: For jQuery 1.4.2 or lower use bind after the append?

Comment: Using `bind()` is like using `click()` but you would have to execute it after appending the HTML as those methods only work if the elements are in the DOM. As `delegate` was added in 1.4.3, if you would be using 1.4.2 or lower you cannot use it. Though `live()` existed in 1.4.2 it had other issues and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Because dynamic content event must be bound using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function :

```
$("body").on('click','.addCategoryBtn',function() {  
       console.log('add category clicked');
});
```

Comment: And in the unlikely event OP is using jQuery 1.6.x or lower use `delegate` as `on` was only added in 1.7.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' `

Comment: Which JQuery version are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I am bound to 1.4.4.

Comment: @doonot: Then use `delegate` which added in 1.4.3

Comment: Pretty old... In this case, check @FrançoisWahl answer which is a goos summary

Comment: And an advice for your next question, don't forget to specify your JQuery version

Comment: +1 @sdespont: Specially now with 1.9 having removed all previously deprecated feature it is even more important than ever indeed.